# Dynamic Reactive Form using Angular

Tags: angular

I have created a dynamic reactive form which is working fine except for the first item of the `FormArray` which is displayed as null.

Current Output
[image: Current Output]

Expected Output
[image: Expected Output]

Subsequent items of the array are generated fine. And if I delete the first item after generating other items, the data is saved correctly.

I see the following error on the console and have tried looking for a solution but according to various answers on the web I have done it correctly.

> ```
> ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'contentBoxes -> 0 -> contentType'
>
> Unable to display error. Open your browser's console to view.
>
> Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
>
> ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'contentBoxes -> 0 -> revenueShare'
>
> Unable to display error. Open your browser's console to view.
> ```

Code can be viewed and run here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ui5n8c

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put a reference of the function at index 0: `this.buildGroup`; that should of course be: `this.buildGroup()`. That way the function will be invoked and the actual object will be returned. So your problem is, the function is not being executed.

So to summarize:

```

```
  buildArray(): FormArray {
    this.contentBoxes = this._fb.array([
      this.buildGroup() // <---- notice the () I added, these are needed!
      //this._fb.control('')
    ]);
    return this.contentBoxes;
  }
```

```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I spent 2 sleepless nights trying to figure out the problem.